# jQueryUI autoselect combobox events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've implemented the jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox widget found here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox.

The autocomplete is working, and the "select" event is firing successfully when an item is clicked from the result values. Using the keyboard to scroll through and select an item will also fire the "select" event.

Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful to get the other events like "change", "close" and "search" to fire, which means that if a valid value is "foo" and the user simply types "foo" without clicking a result, the underlying value isn't being set. The same is true if the user has selected "bar" and then clears the search text - the underlying value remains "bar".

Looking at the API documentation the "change" event supposedly is attached to the "autocompletechange" event, but binding to that has no effect either.

```
$( '#my-select' ).combobox({
    change: function( event, ui ){
        // does not fire
        console.log('change', event, ui, $(this).val());
    },
    close: function( event, ui ){
        // does not fire
        console.log('close', event, ui, $(this).val());
    },
    search: function( event, ui ){
        // does not fire
        console.log('search', event, ui, $(this).val());
    },
    select: function( event, ui ){
        // this will fire when a menu item is clicked
        console.log('select', event, ui, $(this).val());
    }
});

$( '#my-select' ).on( 'autocompletechange', function( event, ui ){
    // does not fire
    console.log('autocompletechange', event, ui, $(this).val());
});
```

See it not working in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s56n2pzz/

I noticed that the event fired on the "change" event has a `type` of "comboboxselect" and the `originalEvent.type` is "autocompleteselect", however binding to things like "comboboxchange" don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue after looking more into the "comboboxselect" event that was appearing instead of "autocompleteselect". The `jQuery.widget` code that creates the combobox wraps the autocomplete, and thus the events. Upon closer inspection of the example code I can see that when an "autocompleteselect" event is fired, it triggers a "select" event on the parent combobox - passing the original event along.

The "autocompletechange" method is implemented, but it does not fire a change event on the parent, only checks to see if the input is valid, and doesn't clear the value if it is not... seems like a bug in the example?

From the example linked in the question:

```
this._on( this.input, {
    // "select" is fired on the combobox
    autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
        });
    },

    // change is NOT fired on the combobox
    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
});
```